# Standard behavior for controls, components and types

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

Has anyone struggled with standardizing for example look and feel of a larger application (a few hundred thousand lines of code)?

For example, lets say I have a lot (hundreds) of combo boxes and text boxes in my application and I want all of them to have green foreground color and blue border. Then after some time the boss says "I want bold text in all combo boxes and text boxes".

One option is to do it manually, but this approach is not good because:
- it is time consuming
- it is suffer for developer
- errors will occur (somewhere in the application there will be text box or combo box which will not have bold text)

What I am searching is a way to do that automatic (automatic applying of properties) or to at least do automatic checking (in a way like code analysis works).

Has someone  done anything similar or has expirience on that field?

Comment: Everything, actually. 
My example is indeed taken from WinForms. In WPF this is a bit easier to achieve.

Comment: WebForms, MVC, and WPF are a different animal, because they utilize style sheets, which means these sorts of changes are trivial unless they have a large impact on layout (large changes in positioning, sizing, etc.). It's another matter on WinForms.

Comment: I do agree. In Web and WPF related technologies this is pretty easy to achieve. Though in WinForms (and in general this is hard to achieve). Maybe PostSharp?

Answer (score 1):

**Winforms specific suggestion/answer**

It would take a larger effort to setup, assuming that is that you have an already existing project with thousands of already created so and so...but use personally extended base objects.

My own project is written in winforms and although we didn't create custom controls, we do have a custom "UserControl" and a custom "Form" that we extend.  The extended forms inherit all the formatting, structures, etc etc and so on from the base forms.  In this case its colors, properties, highlighting, and other contained controls (like a default 'close' button on the form), and custom events as well.

You could create something like this:

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public override <propertyName> { get; set; } //auto-implemented property        
    ...
    public CustomTextBox() : base()
    {
         propertyName = newDefualtValue;
         ...
    }
}
```

This still allows those properties to be set manually on an instance basis...but now there is a new default value defined for them.  This could take a LOT of editing for an existing project though.

This is probably the simplest way to set things up such that the default value for a LARGE base of distributed, yet functionally identical, objects can be changed without having to edit them individually.  Your only other real options are code searches, search and replace operations, and extensive testing.

Comment: When using custom controls, copy/paste, search/replace errors will happen. There is no cure for that. People are error prone thus someone will have to check the code and fix the errors. And this can take huge amount of time. I would like to find a solution which will take this burden off programmer. For example, we already use custom Form and UserControl base classes. I could extend them with ability to apply properties to specific types/members via reflection. Then I can make StyleCop rule which prohibits using forms and user controls which do not inherit from descendants. What do you think?

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  Be careful when adding reflection based anything though.  Its practically all string based, so you have to add a lot of null checks and/or custom exceptions when someone sends in a poorly formatted or spelled property string.  I like the idea of the style rule though, force them to use the custom classes...that way you don't have to worry about it later.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I have implemented the solution in which I created custom base form and control implementations, adding one property and overriding the OnLoad method:

```
public partial class FormBase : Form   
{
    public FormBase ()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected ConsistencyManager ConsistencyManager { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        if (this.ConsistencyManager == null)
        {
            this.ConsistencyManager = new ConsistencyManager(this);
            this.ConsistencyManager.MakeConsistent();
        }
    }
}
```

The ConsistencyManager class finds all controls, components and also supports search of custom child controls within specific control. Copy/paste of code from MakeConsistent method:

```
public void MakeConsistent()
{
    if (this.components == null)
    {
        List<IComponent> additionalComponents = new List<IComponent>();

        // get all controls, including the current one 
        this.components =
            this.GetAllControls(this.parentControl)
            .Concat(GetAllComponents(this.parentControl))
            .Concat(new Control[] { this.parentControl });

        // now find additional components, which are not present neither in Controls collection nor in components
        foreach (var component in this.components)
        {
            IAdditionalComponentsProvider provider = GetAdditinalComponentsProvider(component.GetType().FullName);

            if (provider != null)
            {
                additionalComponents.AddRange(provider.GetChildComponents(component));
            }
        }

        if (additionalComponents.Count > 0)
        {
            this.components = this.components.Concat(additionalComponents);
        }
    }

    this.MakeConsistent(this.components);
}
```

If anyone would like full sample or source let me know.

Best regards, 
Zvonko

PS: In the same manner I have also created the performance counter that counts number of invocations on main thread.